# How to assign vertex group to single bone

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, vertex-groups

I'm trying to animate a simple character in blender. I made a very simple armature, with a bone for every moving part of the mesh. Each moving part is "stored" in a vertex group, and I would like to parent every vertex group to it's corresponding bone. I searched very much on the internet but I didn't find anything useful, even though it seems to be a simple task. Don't tell me to separate the vertex groups into split objects, since I want them to remain connected.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try this: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?248419-Parenting-Vertex-Groups-To-Bones Otherwise, it seems as if you have not simply parented the mesh to the armature. It seems you have done manual weights before parenting. This is generally not the advised course of action.

Comment: ^ Nope you can actually do the weights whenever it suits you. You just need armature modifier and the vertex groups that match to the bone names.

Comment: I know you don't want to be _told_, but if you have non deforming seperate parts I'd parent them as individual objects to the bones.

Answer (score 38):

Just name your vertex groups the same as your bones. The bone named "hand.left" will animate the "hand.left" group (by default the weights are set to 1).
Then both select the mesh and the armature (in this order) and parent it (ctrl+p) with empty groups.

Comment: Thank you for this! As a new user of Blender I found it quite unintuitive that bones are linked to vertex groups solely based on their name.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the vertex group of the mesh and you want to weigh that part to bone, first, in Edit Mode select the vertex group you need, then go to Weight Paint, choose the bone, click on the vertex selection button

[image]

and select vertex group that you need. 
Now you can paint or fill that vertex's with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>