# How do i made a vertex group for all objects

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have several objects that all make up one big person. I want to rig this person but I can't because whenever I add a vertex group to weight paint, it only adds it to one of the objects. I don't understand how I'm supposed to rig several objects as one body (without merging it as one object, which I cannot do.)

Am I doing something wrong?? People act like weight painting is really simple but they always do it on one big mesh.

Edit: Also how do I attach a vertex group to a bone.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. And the issue with that is that I have several different UV maps I'm using for each object, so I don't think I can merge everything without those being lost. I'll try it though. (EDIT: Thank you so much that seems to be working)

Answer (score 1):

your question for "how do I attach a vertex group to a bone" is answered by [how-to-assign-vertex-group-to-single-bone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52922/how-to-assign-vertex-group-to-single-bone), although you can assign to more than one group in succession, I believe (and then perhaps need to adjust weights if >1 group).  Here I took a sphere and parented it (Armature Envelope weights), which generally would parent it mostly to the right arm and spine area.   I then put the sphere in edit mode, selected some vertices , created and assigned to a new "group1" (just I could select them later if needed), but ALSO assigned them to the automatically created group "hand.L" (left hand).  As you can see when I posed the Armature to swing the Left arm upwards, my selected vertices of the sphere tracked with the left hand position.   Here's my blend example: [image]

[image]